# What does it mean if I see "security recommendation" next to a wifi network?

Tags: ios, wifi

I recently went to a restaurant and found that their wifi network has "security recommendation" next to its name. I've never seen it before, and wonder if it might be a new thing introduced in iOS 10.

[image: iOS wifi security recommemdation]

What does this mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's new with iOS 10.  [Here's an overview](https://www.engadget.com/2016/07/22/ios-10-unsecured-networks/) of the feature by Engadget:

> After connecting to an open network, iOS 10 will display a **"Security Recommendation"** notification beneath the network's name in the WiFi menu settings. When a user opens up the Security Recommendation, they're greeted with a notification that "open networks provide no security and expose all network traffic." There's also a recommendation to configure your router to use AES encryption for the network.

Comment: Of course, given that this is a public restaurant, I don't think that they are interested in using AES encryption for the network, since they would prefer the patrons be able to log in immediately, rather than have to ask for a password. Convenience vs. security.

Comment: True, but Apple doesn't know that so they give a generic recommendation.